# Confusion about weak and strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

This might be rather elementary but I can't seem to find what's wrong with the following argument. I suppose it's something rather trivial.
For operators $T\in B(\mathcal{H})$

We say that $T_i\to T$ weakly if $\forall x,y\in \mathcal{H}$ we have
$$\langle T_i x, y\rangle \to \langle T x, y\rangle$$

We say that $T_i\to T$ strongly if $\forall x\in \mathcal{H}$ we have
$$\| T_ix-Tx\|\to 0$$

What is wrong with the following argument?

since $\langle T_i x, y\rangle \to \langle T_i x, y\rangle$ by linearity this is the same as saying $\langle (T_i-T) x, y\rangle \to 0$.
Now since this holds for any $x$ and $y$ then it holds in particular in the special case when $x=y$. But this would mean that as a special case $$\langle (T_i-T) x, x\rangle=\|T_ix-Tx\|^2 \to 0$$.
This would mean that weak convergence implies strong convergence which is obviously wrong (I know that in fact, it is the other way around).

I seem to be confusing something elementary. Where does my confusion stem from?

Comment: You have an extra $i$ in your definition of weakly convergence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion is the (false) equality
$$
\langle Sx,x\rangle=\|Sx\|^2. 
$$
The actual equality is
$$
\langle S^*Sx,x\rangle=\|Sx\|^2. 
$$
Both equalities agree with $S$ is a projection, i.e. $S=S^*S$, but not in general.

So you have things like the following: if $\{P_j\}$ is a net of projections and it converges weakly to a **projection** P, then [$P_j\to P$ strongly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916785/projection-e-i-to-e-in-wot-is-equivalent-to-converge-in-sot-when-e-is-project). Compare this with [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1277399/22857)  that for any positive contraction $T$ there exists a net $\{P_j\}$ of projections such that $P_j\to T$ weakly.

Answer (score 1):

The last equality you wrote is false.
Take for example $X=\ell^{2}$ the square summable sequences.
Then take $T_{n}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ defined as
$$
T_{n}(x)=(\frac{x_{1}}{n},\,x_{2},\dots,\,x_{n},\,\dots).
$$
This sequence converges weakly to $T(x)=(0,x_{2},\dots,x_{n},\dots):$
$$
\langle \bigl( T-T_{n}\bigr)x,y \rangle = \dfrac{y_{1}x_{1}}{n} \to 0 \quad n \to +\infty.
$$
Despite this fact, if you write your equality you get
$$
\frac{x_{1}^{2}}{n^{2}}=\frac{x_{1}}{n}.
$$